# "kernel driver" in "lspci" output

Tags: kernel

I often use `lspci -v` to check the LKM in use for particular hardware device. LKMs are listed as "Kernel modules" and can be seen with `lsmod`. However, what is a "Kernel driver"? For example here:

[image: bcma-pci-bridge on in lspci output]

Is the "bcma-pci-bridge" a module built into kernel(I'm using 3.11.0) and thus it's not loadable and thus it will not appear in `lsmod`, can not be unloaded with `modprobe -r` or checked with `modinfo`?

Comment: What does `lspci -k` show for it?

Comment: @jordanm `lspci -k` shows also "bcma-pci-bridge".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From checking `/boot/config-3.11.0-13-generic` (yours might be different), I would guess that it's built into the kernel, thus you can't unload/reload it.

```
$ grep -i BCMA /boot/config-3.11.0-13-generic 
[...]
CONFIG_BCMA_HOST_PCI_POSSIBLE=y
CONFIG_BCMA_HOST_PCI=y
[...]
```

Comment: I have exactly the same configuration options in /boot/config-3.11.0-12-generic. This means that if I want to use some other driver for this particular Wi-Fi card, I need to recompile the kernel?

Comment: @Martin - I would assume so.